# Es posible ejecutar un loop if controlado por un input en python?

Tags: python

soy novato en python. Tengo este código para generar balotas de bingo simuladas:

```py
import random
letras = ['B','I','N','G','O']
randomletras = random.randint(0,4)
numeros = range(1,51)
randomnumeros = random.randint(0,49)
print((letras[randomletras]) + "-" + str(numeros[randomnumeros]))

print ("Nueva balota: s/n ?")
balota = input ("")

if balota =='s':
#aquí necesito volver a ejecutar todo el código anterior y volver a formular la pregunta           
#else:
    #print ('************fin del juego***********')
```

de manera que se generen balotas aleatorias, hasta que se seleccione 'n'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

usa funciones

```
import random
def nueva_balota():
    letras = ['B','I','N','G','O']
    randomletras = random.randint(0,4)
    numeros = range(1,51)
    randomnumeros = random.randint(0,49)
    print((letras[randomletras]) + "-" + str(numeros[randomnumeros]))

nueva_balota()#llamamos a la funcion
while True:
   print ("Nueva balota: s/n ?")
   balota = input ("")

   if balota =='s':
     nueva_balota() #se vuelve a llamar 
   else:
     print ('************fin del juego***********') 
     break
```

Comment: me ejecuta una vez más el código, pero en seguida se cierra el programa. Hay alguna forma de ejecutarlo tantas veces como se seleccione 's'?

Comment: se me olvido poner el bucle  while ya lo he actualizado

Comment: Muchísimas gracias. Solucionado